# Mmap : failing with MAP_SYNC

Tags: c++, mmap

[linux kernel 6.1.27 on Debian testing, up to date. Clang 16 or gcc 12.2]

May someone tell we what's wrong and why mmap returns MAP_FAILED:

```
int fd = ::open( file_name.data(), O_RDWR );
auto *ptr = mmap( nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_SYNC, fd, 0 );
```

Errno tells: "Operation not supported"

Everything works as expected when removing MAP_SYNC.

It also works when specifying `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MS_SYNC` or `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE |MS_ASYNC`.

I basically want to avoid calling msync after writing and have the kernel manage that for me automatically.

Comment: On failure `mmap` also puts an error code in `errno`. What error do you get, exactly?

Comment: @Botje: yes, sure: "Operation not supported"

Comment: Did you mount your filesystem with `-o dax=always` or set the `FS_XFLAG_DAX` flag on the file? (if you want to use `MAP_SYNC`  then the file must support [direct file access (DAX)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/dax.txt), otherwise the operation fails with `EOPNOTSUPP` (Operation not supported) - see [`mmap` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) (the underlying block device must of course also be DAX-capable)

Comment: @Turtlefight: I think dax activation is the issue here. https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/dax.html#details, When you use xfs, you have xfs_io but for ext4, we don't have anything, right?

Comment: ext4 does support dax (assuming the underlying block device does as well), you can either mount your filesystem with `-o dax=always` to enable dax for all files or set the dax flag on the inode. I'm not aware of any rebuilt cli program like xfs_io for ext4, but maybe there is one. Setting it from code is not too difficult - you just need to issue an ioctl on the file with `FS_IOC_GETFLAGS` / `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` and set the [`EXT4_DAX_FL` flag](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L444).

Comment: Thanks a lot, do not hesitate to mark it as an answer, I will accept it ASAP. :)